# Flutter Location plugin not retrieving location data in iOS simulator with "custom location"

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, geolocation, location

I'm building a Flutter app that requires location data. I'm using the 'Geolocator' and 'Location' plugin to retrieve the user's coordinates. When I set the simulator location to "Custom Location", the location.getLocation() method doesn't seem to execute. However, if I set it to a predefined location like "Apple", it works fine.

Here is my full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart' as loc;
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    location();
    super.initState();
  }

  String? _city;
  String? _country;

  Future<void> location() async {
   
    loc.Location location = loc.Location();

    bool serviceEnabled;
    loc.PermissionStatus permissionGranted;
    loc.LocationData? locationData;

    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (permissionGranted == loc.PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (permissionGranted != loc.PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }
    print('gets always printed');
    locationData = await location.getLocation();
    print('This is not getting printed when location is set on "Custom Location"');
    print(locationData);

    List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        locationData.latitude!, locationData.longitude!);

    setState(() {
      _city = placemarks[0].locality!;
      _country = placemarks[0].country!;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title:const  Text('Location'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Coordinates:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
               
                Text("$_city, $_country", style:const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),)
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
   
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any log that be printed on console?

Comment: locationData = await location.getLocation();
above this function my print() method gets printed but not after.
there is no any other important logs.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: no idea, u may borrow somebody's iPhone :)